# Image Not resizing properly on different devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a mobile page responsive. But keep running into issues where the page don't show up properly on different devices.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width/" >
<title></title>
<link href="css/book.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
    #page {
        background-image: url("images/image-000.jpg");
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my CSS code:

```
body {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

#page {
    height: 1024px;
    width: 768px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
/*  background-image: url("images/img001.png"); - Set in the page header */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: To target different devices with your styles, you will most likely want to introduce media queries to the stylesheet. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: please create jsfiddle which can reproduce your problem and describe a desired effect